# Start tor and polipo when I launch my container

Tags: ubuntu, docker, tor, dockerfile, polipo

I wrote my first Dockerfile in order to test Docker with tor and polipo.
My Dockerfile looks like:

```
# Pull base image.
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Upgrade system
RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y --no-install-recommends && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean

# Install TOR
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tor tor-geoipdb torsocks && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean

# INSTALL POLIPO
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y polipo


# Default ORPort
EXPOSE 9001

# Default DirPort 
EXPOSE 9030

# Default SOCKS5 proxy port 
EXPOSE 9050

# Default ControlPort
EXPOSE 9051
# Default polipo Port
EXPOSE 8123

RUN echo 'socksParentProxy = "localhost:9050"'  >> /etc/polipo/config
RUN echo 'socksProxyType = socks5'  >> /etc/polipo/config
RUN echo 'diskCacheRoot = ""' >> /etc/polipo/config

RUN echo 'ORPort 9001' >> /etc/tor/torrc
RUN echo 'ExitPolicy reject *:*' >> /etc/tor/torrc

RUN mkdir scrapy
ADD scrapyTor scrapy

ADD startpolipotor.sh .
RUN chmod 775 ./startpolipotor.sh
```

my startpolipotor.sh contains 3 lines:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                              
/etc/init.d/tor start &
/etct/init.d/polipo start &
```

But when I launch this command:

```
docker run -i -t id_image /bin/bash
```

And once inside in the container when I launch `ps`, I see nothing.
How I can resolve this?

Comment: your Dockerfile should either have `CMD somecommand` or `ENTRYPOINT somecommand` as last command , or your `docker run` command should launch Tor/Polipo, and after `docker exec` you should do `ps -e`, not `ps` which will only show your process.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Dockerfile` should have a command defined like:

```
CMD ./startpolipotor.sh
```

Then you do not need to provide `/bin/bash` as a `run` command. Only the following should be enough:

```
docker run -i -t id_image
```

**By the way**: your script file creates two processes running in background. That will not work!

Docker containers need to have always a process in foreground. In your case the container would stop immediately after executing your start script. And while stopping the `SIGTERM` will not properly be sent to those background processes so they will simply get killed and may leave some corrupt data.

You should think about using [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org) instead when you need to have multiple processes in your container started.